# Validate inputbox for special language

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, regex

I wrote a form with a single input that takes the users name only in persian language. at the first time when user keypress, it defines the character. if the character was not persian it prevents to type more and show the error: "change your keybord language to persian" .it works great.but the problem is even if keyboard language was persian at first time it shows the error and in second and third keypressing it will be ok. my question is why the error shows at first time when pressing first letter?

here is my snippet :

```js
document.getElementById('my-text').addEventListener('keypress',function(e){
    var myText = this.value;
    if(!just_persian(myText)){
        $("#error-nwl").text("change your keybord language to persian");
  this.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 2px 1px #E25249";
   $("#error-nwl").css('color', '#ff6666');
        this.value = myText.substring(0, myText.length - 1);
  
    }
 else{
  $("#error-nwl").text("");
  this.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0px"; 
  }
});
function just_persian(str){
    var p =  /^[\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF ]+$/;
    return p.test(str);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="error-nwl"></div>
    <form action="" method="post" name="myForm" class="newslside">
        <input type="text" placeholder="register-name" id="my-text"/><br/>
    <input class="submitnews" type="submit" value="send">
    </form>



    
</body>
</html>
```

thanks

Comment: What happens if you add `console.info(str)`? Is the character within the range you expect? I don't know how persian is input but maybe the text is a combination of several code points, so when you start typing all the code points are not there and so fall outside of the range.

Comment: no. everytime that i press my first letter it shows the error but the error hide when i press the second and third letter.

Comment: So what does it show for `console.info(str)` on the first letter?

Comment: @this.lau_ where can i find the console.info(str)?

Comment: Try changing `keypress` to `keyup`. Or, keep `keypress`, but use `var myText = e.key`.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a keypress event, the `this.value` is empty when you press a key the first time. Thus, your `p.test(str)` returns *false*.

You may either test the whole value *after* a key press, that is, on "keyup" event, or test each char separately by passing `e.key` to the `just_persian` function (then, you can just use a `/[\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF ]/` regex).

Comment: How can i test each char separately in a function?

Comment: `if (/[\u0600-\u06FF\uFB8A\u067E\u0686\u06AF ]/.test(e.key)`.